# Get KProperty of a non-package extension property

Tags: kotlin

In kotlin, you can use the reference operator to get the KProperty of a package extension property like this:

```
val String.extProp: String
    get() = "Some get code"

fun foo() {
    val prop: KProperty<String> = String::extProp
}
```

However, when the extension property is declared inside a class the reference operator no longer works:

```
class Example() {

    val String.extProp: String
        get() = "Some get code"

    fun foo() {
        val prop: KProperty<String> = String::extProp // error
    }

}
```

So what I am wondering is how can I change the problematic line in the second example, so the KProperty is gotten?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you are getting is:

> Error:(y, x) Kotlin: 'extProp' is a member and an extension at the same time. References to such elements are not allowed

There is **no syntax** mechanism to generate a reference to an extension method that also requires a containing class.  Your extension for example might use members of the class, and this would need something like "[bound references](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/5)" coming in Kotlin 1.1 (which I'm not sure will cover this case either, it is currently an [open question](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/bound-callable-references.md#open-questions)).  So for now, there is **no `::` syntax** available.  Things like `Example::String::extProp` are **not** available, neither is the commonly tried `Example::String.extProp` syntax.  But you can find it by reflection.

First you need to know the type you will receive is:

```
KProperty2<INSTANCE, EXTENDING, PROPTYPE>
```

Whereas a normal property on a class is:

```
KProperty1<INSTANCE, PROPTYPE>
```

You need to know that because any call to the `getter` will require the class instance and an instance of the class the property is extending.  So you cannot call it the same way as you would a property reference of a class.

You can use this function to find an extension property declared in a class:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T: Any, EXTENDING: Any, R: Any> KClass<T>.extProp(extends: KClass<EXTENDING>, name: String, returning: KClass<R>): KProperty2<T, EXTENDING, R> {
    return this.declaredMemberExtensionProperties.first {
        it.name == name &&
                it.parameters.size == 2 &&
                it.parameters[0].kind == KParameter.Kind.INSTANCE && it.parameters[0].type == this.defaultType &&
                it.parameters[1].kind == KParameter.Kind.EXTENSION_RECEIVER && it.parameters[1].type == extends.defaultType &&
                it.returnType == returning.defaultType
    } as KProperty2<T, EXTENDING, R>
}
```

This is a bit overkill for the checking but ensures that it is future-proof in case any other types of extensions are added later.  The following is your code updated to use it:

```
class Example() {
    val String.extProp: String
        get() = "howdy $this"

    fun foo() {
        val prop = Example::class.extProp(String::class, "extProp", String::class)
        println(prop.get(this, "stringy"))  // "howdy stringy"
    }
}
```