# Unresolved reference after changing lambda to method reference

Tags: kotlin, method-reference

In the following example ([also on Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/GABDtVHEE)), IntelliJ offers to change the lambda (as in the commented-out first line of `main`) to a method reference (as shown in the second line of `main`).

```
fun Int.matches1(n: Int): Boolean = TODO()
fun Int.matches2(n: Int): Boolean = TODO()

fun main() {
    // val matches: Int.(Int) -> Boolean = { n -> matches1(n) }
    val matches: Int.(Int) -> Boolean = ::matches1
}
```

The line containing the lambda works fine. However, if I try to use the method reference, the Kotlin compiler rejects it with `Unresolved reference: matches1`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the receiver type, since you're trying to reference an extension function. It's similar to when you want to reference a function that belongs to a class. So this works:

```
val matches: Int.(Int) -> Boolean = Int::matches1
```

Comment: Doing so yields the following in my IntelliJ: `'matches1' is a member and an extension at the same time. References to such elements are not allowed`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562039/kotlin-member-and-extension-at-the-same-time) for more.

Comment: @Endzeit Did you put `matches1` and `matches2` in a class? I do not get the error if I put them at top level.

Comment: @Sweeper: or in a scratch file, where the top level only seems to be top level.

Comment: @Sweeper Huh, that's interesting. I indeed used a scratch file.

Comment: @lukas.j Thanks for pointing that out.